# Pre-processor macro variables

Tags: c, hash, struct, c-preprocessor, assign

I have the code:

```
#DEFINE NEW = 1;
```

And a Struct:

```
typedef struct PCB
{

 /*Process state:new, ready, running, waiting, terminated*/
 int state;
 }PCB;
```

How can I assign NEW, such that state=1?

More info, I get the error:

```
expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
```

Comment: `#DEFINE NEW = 1;` remove the semicolon and the '=', and convert to lowercase.

Comment: These are called preprocessor macros, not "hash defined variables". I suggest you read up on the basics of C before trying to write en entire OS.

Comment: sorry man was just a quick question which could not remember from last years programming, i'm a noob to c and forgot. and i'm not writing a entire os, just a processes scheduler. which is very hard for me.. but thanks

Comment: thought it was hash defined variable, because of hash and variable name which u define

Comment: BTW: you cannot initialize in a struct definition (or a typedef) . First: define a structure, Then use (instantiate) it, maybe using the expansion of the NEW macro.

Comment: Yes just saw that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove both semicolon and the `=`

`#DEFINE NEW 1`